# Bind command to unused F7 key

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a Dell XPS 13 from 2016. The F7 key is unused. The other F-keys are bound to xf86 keys.

I want to turn my F7 key into a screen off key, running

```
xset dpms force off
```

but custom shortcuts can't use just 1 key. In dconf-editor, I manually changed the keybinding for this custom shortcut to F7, but it's still unrecognized.

Using `xbindkeys` to check the tag for F7, I see that F7 is indeed correct. However, after manually changing the setting in dconf-editor,  `xbindkeys` doesn't detect a keypress for F7 key.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I'm running Loki, everything up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Applications --> System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts

Select the Custom set on the left, then click the '+' button. Enter the command and options you want to run and then click where it says Disabled. Hit the F7 key and you should see it says F7 instead of Disabled.

You need to log out and back in for this to take effect (as it says at the top).